# URLConnection class of java giving connection time out exception on linux ec2 server but the same code works for me on localhost

Tags: java, linux, amazon-web-services, server

Actually, I am using GSM modem application which send SMS from my mobile, and mobile is a server to send messages from any java code.

While I run the spring boot application on localhost, it works perfectly for me, but after uploading it on server, it gives Connection time out error.

I am using Linux server provided by AWS ec2 instance.

Answer (score 0):

Where is your server which handles SMS sending? It looks like it is located on your local machine, and after you have deployed your app to Amazon, there is no more routing from AWS to your local computer. You need to deploy your SMS server to routable (external IP) to let the AWS server access to SMS server

Comment: I have android application which create a server to send SMS, so my android mobile works as a server to send SMS.

Comment: So, is it possible that an android device blocking HTTP requests sent from the AWS server? because my AWS server is outside of the country.

Comment: which IP address do you use to access your smartphone?
it should be external, routable,
not 192.168.x.x or 10.x.x.x
mobile operators provide for you also inner (black, unroutable) IP addresses

Comment: I am using IP address which is generated by the application (192.168.54.x)

Comment: what should I do?

Comment: This IP address given not by your application, but by your router. There is no easy answer on thins question. You need to obtain External (routable) IP address and setup port forwarding. This is completely different topic outside the spring and AWS.